# Get elasticsearch result based on two keys

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get all docs who's "PayerAccountId" should equal to "123" and "UsageStartDate" should be in range [2015-05-01 TO 2015-05-10]

I am expecting something to run like this,

```
 curl -X GET http://192.168.1.3:9200/_all/_search -d '{"query" : {"match" : { "PayerAccountId:\"156023466485\" AND UsageStartDate:[2015-01-01 TO 2015-01-10]" }}}'
```

Obviously it's not working any suggestions

Here is my one doc

```
    {
  "_index": "logstash-2015.04.01",
  "_type": "sam_billing_hourly",
  "_id": "ef06aeb5fbab7191a43335740779fc73b667ff0b",
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_source": {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2015-04-01T02:00:00.000Z",
    "Operation": "A",
    "PayerAccountId": "156023466485",
    "PricingPlanId": 482457,
    "RateId": 3035133,
    "RecordType": "LineItem",
    "UnBlendedCost": 4.0e-07,
    "UnBlendedRate": 4.0e-07,
    "UsageEndDate": "2015-04-01T03:00:00Z",
    "UsageQuantity": 1,
    "UsageStartDate": "2015-04-01T02:00:00Z",
    "UsageType": "DNS-Queries",
    "fingerprint": "ef06aeb5fbab7191a43335740779fc73b667ff0b"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `query_string` not a `match`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "PayerAccountId:\"156023466485\" AND UsageStartDate:[2015-01-01 TO 2015-10-01]"
    }
  }
}
```